# Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я поняла

Tags: фонетика

В каком слове самое большое количество согласных звонких звуков: **солнце, канистра, зубик, белье**?
У меня получилось - в слове **зубик**, так как *л, н, р* - согласные сонорные звуки. Правильно ли я поняла?

Answer (score 3):

> В каком слове самое большое количество согласных звонких звуков:
>   солнце, канистра, зубик, белье?

В слове ***бельё.*** См.: [**б**]е[**л'**][**й'**/о] -- 3 звонких звука.

**P.S.**

[Звуки [й], [л], [л′], [м], |м′], [н], [н′], [р], [р′] не образуют соот­носительной пары с глухими согласными, следовательно, они являются **непарными звонкими** (непарные звонкие согласные еще называются **сонорными**).](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=622dc11c-0234-4289-9124-92c5c338321a)

Такое же деление согласных на **звонкие** и **глухие** и [у Литневской](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm#6_1):

> **Звонкие** состоят из шума и голоса. При их произношении воздушная струя не только преодолевает преграду в полости рта, но и колеблет
>   голосовые связки. **Звонкими являются следующие звуки: [б], [б’], [в],
>   [в’], [г], [г’], [д], [д’], [ж], [з], [з’], [й’], [л], [л’], [м],
>   [м’], [н], [н’], [р], [р’].** Звонким является также звук [ж’],
>   встречающийся в речи отдельных людей в словах дрожжи, вожжи и
>   некоторых других.
>
> **Глухие** согласные произносятся без голоса, когда голосовые связки остаются расслабленными, и состоят только из шума Глухими являются
>   следующие согласные звуки: [к], [к’], [п], [п’], [с], [с’], [т], [т’],
>   [ф], [ф’], [х], [х’] [ц], [ч’], [ш], [щ’].
>
> ...Соотношение тона и шума у звонких согласных неодинаково: у парных
>   звонких шума больше, чем тона, у непарных шума меньше, чем тона,
>   поэтому глухие и парные звонкие в лингвистике называют шумными, а
>   **непарные звонкие [й'], [л], [л'], [м], [м'], [н], [н'], [р], [р'] – сонорными**.

Comment: А почему  сонорные содержат  шум, но при этом противопоставляются шумным согласным?

Comment: Почему противопоставляются? Интенсивность шума у шумных согласных **значительно** выше, чем у сонорных. Из Литневской: _"у парных звонких **шума больше, чем тона**, у непарных_  [сонорных]  _**шума меньше, чем тона**"._

Comment: Я говорю про терминологию, насколько она удачна. Все согласные мы делим на сонорные и шумные, но ведь в сонорных шум также присутствует, хотя и в малом количестве.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, если считать, что все согласные делятся на три группы: сонорные, звонкие и глухие.

Comment: Классификаций много разных, есть и такая, кто-то сонорные называет сонантами: Сонанты, у которых голос преобладает над шумом (м, н, л, p).
Шумные звонкие. Шум преобладает над голосом (б, в, д, з, ж).
Шумные глухие, которые произносятся без голоса (п, ф, т, с, ш ).В школе сонорные и звонкие объединили, потому что в образовании их принимает участие голос, а в глухих нет.Думаю, этого достаточно для базовых знаний.

Comment: Вопрос даже не в том, как назвать звуки Л, М, Н, Р - сонорными или сонантами, тем более в школьной практике. Вопрос в том, насколько школьники понимают, насколько важно именно  в ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ выделить сонорные в отдельную группу.

Comment: А где  в ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ  важно выделять сонорные в отдельную группу?

Comment: У парных звонких/глухих согласных сильная позиция перед сонорными (как и перед гласными), поэтому их не надо проверять, а напротив, сонорные можно использовать для проверки. И по акустике сонорные ближе к гласным, чем к звонким согласным.